# visual studio- cannot scroll file width

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I work in visual-studio 2012 softwere.

Suddenly, the scroll button become disable, **only for js files**.
The code lines are cut, and it is really uncomfortableand.
I don't know how to enable it.

[image: See the picture:[enter image description here][1]]

Comment: Looks like you have line wrap or word wrap turned on, so there is nothing to scroll...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> JavaScript`.

On the `General` subpage, make sure `Word wrap` is unchecked. 
On the `Scroll Bars` subpage, make sure the option for `Show horizontal scroll bar` is checked.